# Не переведены тексты во "Временной шкале"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, временная-шкала

Не переведены тексты во "Временной шкале"

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил:

1. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14118

   > Показать итоги голосования
2. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14114

   > Скрыть итоги голосования
3. https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14113

   > Фильтр событий